Extjs 4.2 JavaScript_Server_Side_Vulnerabilities/Stored_Code_Injection
My customer's company run a vulnerability check with some tool and (aside others) found the vulnerability "JavaScript_Server_Side_Vulnerabilities/Stored_Code_Injection" on the extjs base code.
In particular:
from /extjs/ext-debug.js in line 16894 to line 21070
        selectNode : function(path, root){
            return Ext.DomQuery.select(path, root, null, true)[0]; //<- line 16894
        },

        update : function(html, loadScripts, callback) {
            var me = this,
                id,
                dom,
                interval;

            if (!me.dom) {
                return me;
            }
            html = html || '';
            dom = me.dom;

            if (loadScripts !== true) {
                dom.innerHTML = html;
                Ext.callback(callback, me);
                return me;
            }

            id  = Ext.id();
            html += '<span id="' + id + '"></span>';

            interval = setInterval(function() {
                var hd,
                    match,
                    attrs,
                    srcMatch,
                    typeMatch,
                    el,
                    s;
                if (!(el = DOC.getElementById(id))) {
                    return false;
                }
                clearInterval(interval);
                Ext.removeNode(el);
                hd = Ext.getHead().dom;

                while ((match = scriptTagRe.exec(html))) {
                    attrs = match[1];
                    srcMatch = attrs ? attrs.match(srcRe) : false;
                    if (srcMatch && srcMatch[2]) {
                       s = DOC.createElement("script");
                       s.src = srcMatch[2];
                       typeMatch = attrs.match(typeRe);
                       if (typeMatch && typeMatch[2]) {
                           s.type = typeMatch[2];
                       }
                       hd.appendChild(s);
                    } else if (match[2] && match[2].length > 0) {
                        if (window.execScript) {
                           window.execScript(match[2]);
                        } else {
                           window.eval(match[2]); //<- line 21070
                        }
                    }
                }
                Ext.callback(callback, me);
            }, 20);
            dom.innerHTML = html.replace(replaceScriptTagRe, '');
            return me;
        },

anybody found the same issue and knows how to fix it?
many thanks
did't find anythink in the forums
